# simple htaccess issue

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a simple htaccess issue.
In my localhost I have a folder mysite. mysite has three subfolders.

1. html
2. dev
3. images

I have put my htaccess in mysite folder. My rule is if anyone access site through http://localhost/mysite it should read files from html folder.
My current htaccess is follows

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|dev|js|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ html/index.html$1 [L]
```

That is `http://localhost/mysite/aboutus.html should show files in   http://localhost/mysite/html/aboutus.html`

-Arun

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ html/$1 [QSA]
```

To clarify a bit more, it doesn't rewrite any existing files and directories and rewrites everything to the directory html.

Comment: @sitesafe, its now just showing the site directory(index of mysite).

Comment: @user504383 what is the URL you are requesting? It should be index.html, and the file should exist in the directory html/

Comment: Modify your directory index http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-display-or-change-a-default-page-other-than-indexhtml/

Comment: @sitesafe, one more doubt, I want to include one more condition. if we access the url without any page, it should redirect to html/index.html. I mean http://localhost/mysite/ should load http://localhost/mysite/html/index.html

Comment: @user504383 Before RewriteEngine On, insert: DirectoryIndex html/index.html

Comment: @SiteSafeNL, Thanks. atlast everything working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: In this case I have same copy of html files in both folders. That is in html and dev folders. Files in each folder accessing same images folder. So how can I refer the images in the html files? 
If I put <img src='images/a.jpg'> It will work in localhost/mysite/about.html file. But it will not work in dev folder files. I know that there is no images folder in the dev folder. So Is there any htaccess trick to access the same image folder for my two folders?